# Rails 5.2 App push to Heroku successful. Heroku open fails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, heroku-postgres, buildpack

I successfully pushed a rails 5.2 app to Heroku, but there is an error somewhere. After this:

`Heroku open`

The browser shows this:

`An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served.`

In the terminal, when I type:

`heroku ps`

I get this:

`web (Free): bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV (1) web.1: crashed`

I am not sure where to look to troubleshoot this. I am new to programming and very new to Heroku.

If there is other information that would be useful, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to allow the error messages in production to check the exception? . To Do it change these line on prodction.rb file:   `config.consider_all_requests_local = true`. Doesn't forget to turn it off again later.

Comment: Install Heroku CLI, connect and type `heroku logs --tail` it will show the app logs.

Comment: @Maxence Thanks. That pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your Rails 5.2 app is not serving on Heroku, use this for a detailed error log. It's extremely helpful.

`$ heroku run rails console`